# jquery how to select the next element after the current element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="main">
  <ul>
    <li><div></div></li>
  </ul>
  <div>needs to be selected</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

How can I select, using jquery, only the first div inside the main div?

Or

How can I select, using jquery, only the first div after `<ul>`?

I tried doing this but didn't work:

```
$('#main ul').next('div:first').addClass('my_class');
```

Comment: The jQuery you provided works given the markup you posted http://jsfiddle.net/21xfg8b0/

Comment: Thanks. But this still is not solving my problem. I don't know why in my case it won't select the right element.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors):

```
$('#main > div').addClass('my_class');
```

If you have more than one direct child `div` and want the first one, you can do:

```
$('#main > div').first().addClass('my_class');
```

The easiest way would be to add a class to the `div` you are interested in so that you can easily identify it:

```
<div class="to-be-selected">needs to be selected</div>
```

then

```
$('#main > div.to-be-selected').addClass('my_class');
```

or even

```
$('#main .to-be-selected').addClass('my_class');
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply like that.

```
$("#main").find("ul").next().addClass("my_class");
```

Hope it will be work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Standard CSS selectors will do, no need for jQuery extravaganza:

First `div` inside `#main`, using [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type):

```js
jQuery('#main > div:first-of-type').addClass('my_class').
```

First `div` after `ul`, using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

```js
jQuery('#main > ul + div').addClass('my_class');
```